# Error when programmatically injecting translated products in Kentico, am I doing it right?

Tags: e-commerce, kentico

For information I've installed a fresh new version of Kentico v12 and i'm using the basic goat template.

I have a list of products in a webservice (it's my source of truth) that I would like to inject in 
the backoffice of Kentico.

The products received from the webservice are related to the language in which they are translated.
If I have 2 languages, let's say dutch and french i'll get each products 2 times.

Practical example:

Let's say my webservice has only 1 product but recognize 2 languages, when I consume it i'll receive 2 products.

- ProductId: 1, Language: NL, Name: NameTranslatedInDutch
- ProductId: 1, Language: FR, Name: NameTranslatedInFrench

My identifier that allows me to group them is the field "ProductId"

To create a new culture version of my product I use the method "InsertAsNewCultureVersion" of TreeNode.

When I execute it I get this error:

[image]

My code:

```
                // I search all documents related to the ProductId received from the webservice
                var document = DocumentHelper
                         .GetDocuments()
                         .OnSite("Goat")
                         .Culture(facet.Language)
                         .Path("/", PathTypeEnum.Children)
                         .Where(
                           new WhereCondition(
                               "DocumentName",
                               QueryOperator.Equals,
                               facet.ProductId))
                         .FirstOrDefault();

                // If it already exists I only have to update it
                if (document != null)
                {
                    UpdateProductTreeNode(facet, document);
                }
                // Otherwise i need to insert a new culture version
                else
                {
                    // I search for the first possible version for my product
                    var baseDocument = (SKUTreeNode)DocumentHelper
                         .GetDocuments()
                         .OnSite("Goat")
                         .Path("/", PathTypeEnum.Children)
                         .Where(
                           new WhereCondition(
                               "DocumentName",
                               QueryOperator.Equals,
                               facet.ProductId))
                         .FirstOrDefault();

                    // I'm sure it's not null, i've already checked it above but didn't copy/paste this part 
                    baseDocument.InsertAsNewCultureVersion(facet.Language, true); // Exception occurs here

                    var newDocument = DocumentHelper
                         .GetDocuments()
                         .OnSite("Goat")
                         .Culture(facet.Language)
                         .Path("/", PathTypeEnum.Children)
                         .Where(
                           new WhereCondition(
                               "DocumentName",
                               QueryOperator.Equals,
                               facet.ProductId))
                          .FirstOrDefault();

                    UpdateProductTreeNode(facet, newDocument);
                }
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
Should I do it differently ?

Sadly updating the structure of data received from the webservice is not an option.

*The quality of my code is not that good but it's not relevant, i'm doing a proof of concept, the quality will be improved once I'm sure that it works ^^*

I followed those tutorials:

- https://docs.kentico.com/k81/e-commerce-features/customizing-and-developing-your-store/e-commerce-customization-examples/importing-products-using-api
- https://docs.kentico.com/api12/e-commerce/products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the SKUTreeNode that your returning back is a cms.product page type and on insert it requires a column to filled out. By default CMS.Product has two Fields. ProductID, and ProductName.

**Before**

- `baseDocument.InsertAsNewCultureVersion(facet.Language, true)`

**Try**

- `if (baseDocument != null)
      {
          baseDocument.SetValue("ProductName","the name of the product")
      }`

and then call...

- `baseDocument.InsertAsNewCultureVersion(facet.Language, true)`

Let me know if that worked!

Comment: Thank you very much ! This way unlocks me :)

Comment: You're Welcome! Glad to help.